on selecting 2 text on FabricJS (React) and deselect and later select one and deleting that, the old 2 gets deleted

I am making a whiteboard app using react, fabric.js and I have few object functions like square, line, text etc. and also a delete function. on selecting 2 objects and deselect them the again selecting any one object and trying the delete that one object the old 2 objects that I selected before also gets deleted in my delete function here is my code:

Delete logic:
  // delete logic
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvas) return;

    const updateSelectedObjects = (e) => {
      if(e.selected) {
        setSelectedObjects(e.selected);
      } 
    };

    const deleteSelectedObjects = (x) => {
      if(SelectedObjects.length > 0) {
        SelectedObjects.forEach((s) => {
          if(s.isEditing) return;
          canvas.remove(s);
        })
      }
    }

    const keyDownDeleteObjects = (e) => {
      if(e.key == 'Backspace' || e.key == 'Delete' && SelectedObjects.length > 0) {
        SelectedObjects.forEach((s) => {
          if(s.isEditing) return;
          canvas.remove(s);
        })
      }
    }

    const clearSelectedObjects = () => {
      setSelectedObjects([])
    }

    canvas.on('selection:created', updateSelectedObjects)
    canvas.on('selection:updated', updateSelectedObjects)
    canvas.on('selection:cleared', clearSelectedObjects)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownDeleteObjects)

    DelBtn.current.addEventListener('click', deleteSelectedObjects)
  }, [canvas, SelectedObjects]);

  // Show/hide delete button for mobile devices
  useEffect(() => {
    const isTabletOrLower = () => window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches;

    if (isTabletOrLower() && SelectedObjects.length) {
      DelBtn.current.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      DelBtn.current.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, [SelectedObjects]);

*
Text Logic for example, have this issue, including all other logic:*
  // text 
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!canvas) return;

    if(Selected == 'text') {
      // text funcionality
      let textX;
      let textY;
      let text;

      const setCords = (e) => {
        const pointer = canvas.getPointer(e.e) // getPointer by fabric js 
        textX = pointer.x;
        textY = pointer.y;

        let text = new fabric.Textbox("Text", {
          left: textX,
          top: textY,
          fontSize: FONT_SIZE,
          fill: TEXT_COLOR,
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          selectable: true,
          fontFamily: 'Indie Flower',
        })

          // Add text object to the canvas
          canvas.add(text);

          // Make sure the canvas renders the new object first
          canvas.renderAll();

          setTimeout(() => {
            // Select and enter editing mode for the newly added text object
            text.selectAll();
            text.enterEditing();
          }, 100);  // Adjust delay if needed
      }

      canvas.on('mouse:down', setCords);
      canvas.on('touch:down', setCords);

      return () => {
        canvas.getObjects().forEach((obj) => {
          if (obj.isEditing) {
            obj.exitEditing(); // Exit editing mode for the object
          }
        });
        canvas.off('mouse:down', setCords);
        canvas.off('touch:down', setCords);
      }

    }
  }, [Selected, canvas])


I tried to fix this multiple times but, I coudn't find the root of this thing, just completely illogical
